# Adding a path to /etc/paths didn't work

Tags: macos, terminal

I can't use the command cabal directly when it gets some specific arguments. I found a solution but it doesn't work. But it should.

```
$ cabal sandbox init
cabal: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)
```

The solution:

```
$ cat /etc/paths
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
/usr/local/bin
$HOME/.cabal/bin
```

The last line was added by me. However, this still does not work:

```
$ cabal sandbox init
cabal: unrecognised command: sandbox (try --help)
```

But this does:

```
$ $HOME/.cabal/bin/cabal sandbox init
```

Note that this question is not related to cabal per se, it is rather related to Mac OS.

Answer (score 0):

You may have an older version of Cabal installed, and likely in a directory that precedes $HOME/.cabal/bin in your PATH.

Try locating and removing the older version, or just moving $HOME./cabal/bin to the beginning of your PATH.